# Empirical formula of Berthollides

Tags: crystal-structure, notation

Can the empirical formula be defined for berthollides? Is it equal to the molecular formula, or it can't be defined?

Answer (score 4):

"Berthollide" seems to be a word for "non-stoichiometric compound" that has fallen out of use.

You have to look at the structure, as a rule things happen for a reason.  The formula can be derived from the structure.

Consider the series of alums, which is  KAl(SO<sub>4</sub>)<sub>2</sub>·12H<sub>2</sub>O, or more generic:  X<sup>+</sup>Y<sup>3+</sup>(SO<sub>4</sub>)<sub>2</sub>·12H<sub>2</sub>O.  The generic structure can accomodate a monovalent cation, provided it's sufficiently large (lithium is out of the question, sodium is an edge case), and a tervalent cation (Al, Cr, Fe, pretty much anything), and the proportion can be freely chosen within the constraints of the structure.

Comment: What about compounds with non-integer indexes of elements that build it?

Comment: Consider the wuestite structure (Fe(1-x)O).  The ideal structure (FeO) is a sodium chloride structure, but in wuestite phases some octahedral gaps (where you'd ideally find a Fe(2+) ion go unoccupied.

Comment: Can an empirical formula be defined in that case?